# Error with using search plugin for openfire in xcode

Tags: iphone, openfire, xmppframework

Hi I am trying to use search plugin installed for openfire. I am sending an iq request using the code,

```
  NSXMLElement *queryElement = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"query" xmlns:@"jabber:iq:search"];
  NSXMLElement *iqElement = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"iq"];
  [iqElement addAttributeWithName:@"type" stringValue:@"get"];
  [iqElement addAttributeWithName:@"from" stringValue:@"aravind@gotztools"];
  [iqElement addAttributeWithName:@"to" stringValue:@"gotztools"];
  [iqElement addAttributeWithName:@"id" stringValue:@"search1"];
  [iqElement addAttributeWithName:@"xml:lang" stringValue:@"en"];
  [iqElement addChild:queryElement];
  NSLog(@"%@",[iqElement stringValue] );
  [[self appDelegate].xmppStream sendElement:iqElement];
```

while sending, the following request is sent,

```
<iq type="get" from="aravind@gotztools" to="gotztools" id="search1" xml:lang="en">
  <query xmlns="jabber:iq:search"/>
</iq>
```

I am getting an error as,

```
 <iq xmlns="jabber:client" type="error" id="search1" from="gotztools" to="aravind@gotztools/9bd01a04"><query xmlns="jabber:iq:search"/><error code="501" type="cancel"><feature-not-implemented xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/></error></iq>
```

What is the problem with this. Please help me to solve this.
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check whether your search plugin is enabled in openfire admin. You are trying to send request to gotztools. It is just a domain name. Check the search name in Search service Settings in server settings of your openfire admin console. Send request to that Name to get reply. Hope this helps you...